# Avoid writing quotes to text file with comma present in string in Python

Tags: python, csv, file, quote

My code currently searches for files that end with any audio file extension, returns the file name and then stores the path + file name into a text file.

Simple enough, it works, but when scrolling through I noticed some entries have quotes around the entire line. These would be the ones that the file name has a comma in;

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZViQ.png)

This is the code:

```py
def getFiles():
    tracks = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("E:\Music"):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith((".mp3",".m4a",".alac",".flac")):
                tracks.append(root+"\\"+name)
    return tracks

with open("songs.txt", "a") as songsFile:
writeSongsFile = csv.writer(songsFile)
for line in getFiles():
    writeSongsFile.writerow([line])
songsFile.close()
```

How do I write the file path to the text file without the quotes?

Comment: while writing the line do this `name.replace('"', '')`

Comment: Please show us the code that stores the path + file names into a text file.

Comment: Tried this, still prints out with the quotes
EDIT: Updated original post

Comment: I suspect the csv writer is putting those quotes in for a good reason. If you have a track named "A" and a track named "B,C", and you write them to the file without quotes, then it will look like "A,B,C". Now when you read the file back in, how are you supposed to know where one track ends and another begins?

Comment: @SuryaTej The quotes are not in the string.

Comment: The quotes are required in order to prevent the commas from being interpreted.  You should not use commas in folder/file names.

Comment: @Kevin - Yeah I understand. I'm now thinking, I don't need the csv package as I'm not planning on using it in the same manner as a csv file. I just need to output the file paths to a text file, one line per file.

Comment: @CtrlS There's nothing wrong with using commas in a file name. You just need to write code that doesn't *assume* a comma cannot be in a file name.

Comment: @chepner True.  I personally avoid it for simplicity.

Comment: Ok, I have solved the issue. Not using the csv.writer and instead just using the file.write function.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting quotes around any value that has a comma in it is because you're using `csv.writer` to print out your song list.

See, `csv` is a module meant to work with *Comma-Separated Value* files (i.e. spreadsheets where each column is separated by a comma: `col1, col2, col3, ...`). As a result, if one of those columns *contains* a comma, it needs to be escaped, and the most convenient way to do that is by putting the whole thing in quotes. The `csv` module knows this, and does it automatically.

Here, however, it looks like you just want to put this list in a file. No commas or anything, just a list separated by line breaks. In this case, you don't need to use the `csv` module - in fact, I recommend against it, for exactly the issue you're having. Use python's built-in file I/O instead:

```
with open("songs.txt", "a") as songsFile:
    for line in getFiles():
        songsFile.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: This won't work because `[line]` is a list and can't be concatenated with `'\n'`.

Comment: quite right. I have no idea why I put the brackets around it, thanks for bringing that up!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're writing to the file as a CSV, so values with commas are quoted per CSV's format convention.

Since you aren't really using the file as a CSV, you should simply write the file names to the file directly, separated by newlines:

```
with open("songs.txt", "a") as songsFile:
    songsFiles.write('\n'.join(getLines()) + '\n')
```